# Running into issues installing gitlab-shell

Tags: redis, installation, gitlab

I am trying to install Gitlab CE  from source and following this [installation guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/installation.html#7-gitlab).

When I attempt to install the gitlab-shell using the command provided.

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:shell:install REDIS_URL=unix:/var/run/redis/redis.sock RAILS_ENV=production SKIP_STORAGE_VALIDATION=true
```

I received the following stack trace error.

```
WARNING: This version of GitLab depends on gitlab-shell 4.1.1, but you're   running Unknown. Please update gitlab-shell.
rake aborted!
Gitlab::TaskFailedError: Gitlab::TaskFailedError
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/task_helpers.rb:87:in `run_command!'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/task_helpers.rb:164:in `clone_repo'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/task_helpers.rb:157:in     `checkout_or_clone_tag'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/shell.rake:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top    (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:shell:install
```

What config file should I be modifying to fix my issue? Do I need to modify the Redis URL even though I am using the default configuration? By the way, this install is on an Ubuntu 16.04 server.

Comment: I got around this issue by downloading the tar.gz file of gitlab-shell from the project page on gitlab and moving the unzipped folder into /home/git/ (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-shell)

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by using a version of git that is too old.

To debug: append the `--trace` option to `bundle exec` to get more info on where this error is coming from and inspect the source.